# Why explicit cast required when adding int with byte?

Tags: java, variable-assignment, literals

Doing this is legal in Java

```
byte = 27     // 27 treated as int; implicit cast to byte
```

But when assigning a value as a result of expression, Java requires explicit casting

```
int a = 9;
byte b = 8;
byte c = a + b;  // Compile error
```

What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`27` is a literal. The compiler knows that it is representable in a `byte` (from -128 to 127).

`a + b` is an expression involving variables. Its result may not be representable in a `byte`

Comment: That is a great answer. Because I tried byte c = 9 + 8 and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Yes this is just `c = 17` for the compiler.